# Invalid column name when executing named query

Tags: java, sql, spring, oracle, hibernate

I am getting a strange error when executing a named query. It is complaining about an invalid column name.

Here is the named query

```
    <sql-query  name="findCompositionDataPointsApplicableOnDate">
        <return class="com.application.data.domain.datapoint.AbstractDataPoint" />
            <![CDATA[
               select c1.* 
                from data_point c1
                where c1.name = :name 
                and c1.product = :product
                and c1.network_object_id = :networkObject
                and c1.date_effective
                    = (select max(c2.date_effective) 
                    from data_point c2
                    where c2.name = c1.name 
                     and c2.product = c1.product
                     and c2.network_object_id = c1.network_object_id
                    and c2.date_effective <= :gasDay)
                order by c1.id
            ]]>
    </sql-query>
```

These are the exact column names in the database table:

ID,  NETWORK_OBJECT_ID,  NAME,  PRODUCT,  DESCRIPTION,  DATE_EFFECTIVE,  DATA_POINT_TYPE

This is the code that executes the query

```
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    public List<CompositionDataPoint> findEffectiveByNetworkObjectAndNameAndProduct(NetworkObject<Long> networkObject, String name, Product product,
            LocalDate date) {
        SQLQuery query = (SQLQuery) getSession().getNamedQuery("findCompositionDataPointsApplicableOnDate")
        .setParameter("gasDay", convertToDate(date))
        .setParameter("name", name)
        .setParameter("product", product.name().toString())
        .setParameter("networkObject", networkObject.getId());
        return query.list();
    }
```

The named query executes fine when run on sqlDeveloper but when it is executed when running the application, i get the following error.

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column name
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.getColumnIndex(OracleStatement.java:3757)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.InsensitiveScrollableResultSet.findColumn(InsensitiveScrollableResultSet.java:264)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.GeneratedResultSet.getString(GeneratedResultSet.java:594)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingResultSet.getString(DelegatingResultSet.java:263)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingResultSet.getString(DelegatingResultSet.java:263)
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.VarcharTypeDescriptor$2.doExtract(VarcharTypeDescriptor.java:62)
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicExtractor.extract(BasicExtractor.java:47)
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:257)
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:253)
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:243)
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.hydrate(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:329)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.hydrate(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3214)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.loadFromResultSet(Loader.java:1887)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.hydrateEntityState(Loader.java:1811)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.instanceNotYetLoaded(Loader.java:1784)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRow(Loader.java:1624)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRowFromResultSet(Loader.java:748)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRowsFromResultSet(Loader.java:1047)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.processResultSet(Loader.java:998)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:967)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:357)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2868)
    ... 110 more
```

I have also tried reducing the named query to be just something as simple as `Select * from data_point` and it still gives me the same error. I have also tried listing all the column names out in the select but still the same error.

Anymore info you need, let me know

Pretty confused.

edit:

here is the data_point hbm file with the mapping - i cant spot anything wrong with this?

```
<class table="DATA_POINT" 
        name="com.application.data.domain.datapoint.AbstractDataPoint" 
        proxy="com.application.data.domain.datapoint.DataPoint"
        abstract="true"
    >
        <id name="id" type="java.lang.Long">
            <column name="ID" precision="20" scale="0" not-null="true" />
            <generator class="sequence">
                <param name="sequence">DATA_POINT_ID_SEQ</param>
            </generator>
        </id>
        <discriminator column="DATA_POINT_TYPE" type="string" />
        <property name="name" type="string">
            <column name="NAME" length="64" not-null="true" />
        </property>
        <property name="product" type="Product">
            <column name="PRODUCT" length="16" not-null="false" />
        </property>
        <property name="description" type="string">
            <column name="DESCRIPTION" length="128" not-null="true" />
        </property>
        <many-to-one name="networkObject" class="com.application.network.domain.AbstractNetworkObject">
            <column name="NETWORK_OBJECT_ID" not-null="false"/>
        </many-to-one>
        <property name="dateEffective" type="LocalDate">
            <column name="DATE_EFFECTIVE" not-null="true" />
        </property>
```

Here is the full stacktrace

```
Invalid column name
An error occurred during execution of handler: com.web.mvc.composition.ViewMonthlyGasDeliveryCompositionController#display(WebRequest, ViewMonthlyGasDeliveryCompositionSearchCriteria)
org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateJdbcException: JDBC exception on Hibernate data access: SQLException for SQL [select id, network_object_id, product, description, date_effective, data_point_type
               from data_point]; SQL state [99999]; error code [17006]; could not execute query; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not execute query
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.SessionFactoryUtils.convertHibernateAccessException(SessionFactoryUtils.java:252)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateExceptionTranslator.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateExceptionTranslator.java:102)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateExceptionTranslator.java:77)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:61)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:242)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:154)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy104.findEffectiveByNetworkObjectAndNameAndProduct(Unknown Source)
    at com.amor.hcplus.application.data.domain.datapoint.DataPointManagerImpl.getCompositionDataPoints(DataPointManagerImpl.java:43)
    at com.application.network.domain.AbstractNetworkObject.getCompositionDataPoints(AbstractNetworkObject.java:46)
    at com.application.network.domain.AbstractMeteredPoint.createMonthlyGasData(AbstractMeteredPoint.java:412)
    at com.application.composition.domain.CompositionDataRootImpl.getDeliveryPointTotalGasData(CompositionDataRootImpl.java:415)
    at com.service.composition.CompositionServiceImpl.getMonthlyTotalCommingledGasData_aroundBody68(CompositionServiceImpl.java:1263)
    at com.service.composition.CompositionServiceImpl$AjcClosure69.run(CompositionServiceImpl.java:1)
    at org.springframework.transaction.aspectj.AbstractTransactionAspect.ajc$around$org_springframework_transaction_aspectj_AbstractTransactionAspect$1$2a73e96cproceed(AbstractTransactionAspect.aj:67)
    at org.springframework.transaction.aspectj.AbstractTransactionAspect$AbstractTransactionAspect$1.proceedWithInvocation(AbstractTransactionAspect.aj:73)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:367)
    at org.springframework.transaction.aspectj.AbstractTransactionAspect.ajc$around$org_springframework_transaction_aspectj_AbstractTransactionAspect$1$2a73e96c(AbstractTransactionAspect.aj:71)
    at com.service.composition.CompositionServiceImpl.getMonthlyTotalCommingledGasData(CompositionServiceImpl.java:1252)
    at com.web.mvc.composition.ViewMonthlyGasDeliveryCompositionController.display(ViewMonthlyGasDeliveryCompositionController.java:122)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:190)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:105)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:878)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:792)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1043)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:529)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:623)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:209)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:153)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:178)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:153)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:320)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:126)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:90)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:118)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:158)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:200)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:92)
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:77)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.ConcurrentSessionFilter.doFilter(ConcurrentSessionFilter.java:152)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:358)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:271)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:178)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:153)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter.doFilterInternal(OpenSessionInViewFilter.java:156)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:178)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:153)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:167)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:481)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:130)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:93)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:673)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:390)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:63)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:926)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1791)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not execute query
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:42)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:113)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2871)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2850)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2682)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2677)
    at org.hibernate.loader.custom.CustomLoader.list(CustomLoader.java:338)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.listCustomQuery(SessionImpl.java:2186)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.list(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:1204)
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.NativeQueryImpl.doList(NativeQueryImpl.java:177)
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.list(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1617)
    at com.amor.hcplus.application.data.dao.hibernate.CompositionDataPointHibernateDao.findEffectiveByNetworkObjectAndNameAndProduct(CompositionDataPointHibernateDao.java:49)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:344)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:198)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:139)
    ... 93 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column name
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.getColumnIndex(OracleStatement.java:3757)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.InsensitiveScrollableResultSet.findColumn(InsensitiveScrollableResultSet.java:264)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.GeneratedResultSet.getString(GeneratedResultSet.java:594)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingResultSet.getString(DelegatingResultSet.java:263)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingResultSet.getString(DelegatingResultSet.java:263)
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.VarcharTypeDescriptor$2.doExtract(VarcharTypeDescriptor.java:62)
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicExtractor.extract(BasicExtractor.java:47)
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:257)
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:253)
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:243)
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.hydrate(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:329)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.hydrate(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3214)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.loadFromResultSet(Loader.java:1887)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.hydrateEntityState(Loader.java:1811)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.instanceNotYetLoaded(Loader.java:1784)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRow(Loader.java:1624)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRowFromResultSet(Loader.java:748)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRowsFromResultSet(Loader.java:1047)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.processResultSet(Loader.java:998)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:967)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:357)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2868)
    ... 110 more
```

Comment: Is the DAO `CompositionDataPoint` mapped with the same column name?

Comment: Yeah its all mapped correctly - using XML annotation

Comment: The error seems to be from fetching the data from the result set, not executing the query; as it seems to have a problem getting a column index from its name (according to the top of the error stack), it sounds like you might have an incorrect name somewhere in your mapping - possibly just the wrong case?

Comment: let me double check

Comment: You should be able to get rid of the self join by using analytic functions `SELECT *
FROM   (
  select d.*,
         MAX(date_effective) OVER (ORDER BY date_effective DESC)
           AS max_date_effective
  from   data_point d
  where  name = :name 
  and    product = :product
  and    network_object_id = :networkObject
  and    date_effective <= :gasDay
)
WHERE date_effective = max_date_effective
order by id`

Comment: @AlexPoole i have updated the question with my mapping

Comment: I am not a Java expert but can you try this code in your Java `SELECT 1 as ID, 2 as NETWORK_OBJECT_ID, 'My Name' NAME, 'Product 1' PRODUCT, 'working  ' DESCRIPTION, NULL DATE_EFFECTIVE, NULL DATA_POINT_TYPE
` instead of `Select * FROM data_point` and check if it works?

Comment: Is this a similar issue? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41810305/java-sql-sqlexception-invalid-column-name